# Combine LIKE and CONTAINS in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana, fuzzy-search, hana-studio

Consider the following entries in my table:

- red ap**ple**
- yellow ap**ple**
- ap**ple** green
- red a**ple**
- ap**pel** yellow

Several people have populated this table using a non-consistend notation (the color *before* or *after* 'apple'), also entering some spelling errors.
Now I want to query all entries with the word `apple`, regardless of color or spelling.

With `FUZZY()`:

```
SELECT name FROM "NEO_123456789ABCDE"."MYTABLE1" WHERE contains(name, 'apple', FUZZY(0.5))
```

I only get:

- red ap**ple**
- red a**ple**

When adding wildcards:

```
SELECT name FROM "NEO_123456789ABCDE"."MYTABLE1" WHERE contains(name, '%apple%', FUZZY(0.5))
```

I only get all entries, where `apple` was spelled right:

- red ap**ple**
- yellow ap**ple**
- ap**ple** green

Why I can't combine both operators [LIKE](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/fa17f375191014a4d8d8cbfddfe340/content.htm?frameset=/en/20/f952437519101487edc3d9aba84238/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/2e/1ef8b4f4554739959886e55d4c127b/plain.htm&node_id=15) and [CONTAINS](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/9a/4da8f6f23b4ebf95c98f1104a56db4/content.htm) in one query?

I need to find:

- entries, where `apple` is surrounded by other words (in my case colors)
- all forms of `apple` (regardless of the spelling)

Comment: Why not just change the "fuzzy level": `WHERE contains(name, 'apple', FUZZY(0.2))` seems to do what you want.

Comment: a fuzzy value of 0.2 is usually much too low to return meaningful results

Answer (score 2):

```
select name from(
         SELECT name FROM "NEO_123456789ABCDE"."MYTABLE1" WHERE contains(name, 'apple', FUZZY(0.2)) --Part I
         UNION ALL
         SELECT name FROM "NEO_123456789ABCDE"."MYTABLE1" WHERE contains(name, '%apple%') --Part II
)group by name
```

This query basically joins the search results from contains clause with fuzzy search and normal search. You can also replace the Part II of query with like instead.

Comment: You need to format the answer properly and add some explanation for it to be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The fuzzy algorithm matches against the complete content of the column in your example. So it compares "apple" with "red apple" and "appel yellow"

What you want is a matching against the tokens in your columns. You can achieve this by creating a fulltext index, which will tokenize the content in the columns into a fulltext index. contains() will automatically use the fulltext index.

```
drop table MYTABLE1;
create column table MYTABLE1 
(
  name nvarchar(100)
);

insert into MYTABLE1 (name) values ('red apple');
insert into MYTABLE1 (name) values ('yellow apple');
insert into MYTABLE1 (name) values ('apple green');
insert into MYTABLE1 (name) values ('red aple');
insert into MYTABLE1 (name) values ('appel yellow');


CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX i_MYTABLE1 ON MYTABLE1(name) FUZZY SEARCH INDEX ON SYNC;

SELECT name FROM "MYTABLE1" WHERE contains(name, 'apple', FUZZY(0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try the following standard sql query :

```
SELECT name FROM "NEO_123456789ABCDE"."MYTABLE1" WHERE name like '%apple%'
```

This query will select your apples.
Concerning your fuzzy, why not using it with a subquery ?
Something like :

```
    SELECT name FROM "NEO_123456789ABCDE"."MYTABLE1" 
    WHERE contains(name, 'apple', FUZZY(0.5))
    and name in (
    SELECT name FROM "NEO_123456789ABCDE"."MYTABLE1" WHERE name like '%apple%'
    )
```

Comment: But doing so I wouldn't make use of `FUZZY()`. I need this in order to find all spelling errors.

Comment: The result is only `red apple`.